# What are the methods of prophylaxis against exposure to radioactive isotopes?

Tags: cell-biology, medicine, health, radiation, treatment

Potassium iodide is used as prophylaxis to prevent illness when one is likely to be exposed to Iodine-131 and other radioactive isotopes of iodine. Are there any other prophylactic treatments for exposure to other radioactive isotopes, such as Cesium-137, Tritium, Strontium-90, etc? If so, how do they work?

Comment: What research have you done to find this out yourself?

Comment: @David I read the Wikipedia articles on Iodine-131 and Potassium Iodide. I also searched "Tritium Poisoning Treatment" on Google and got this result: https://io9.gizmodo.com/drinking-a-beer-can-save-you-from-radiation-poisoning-1648955835 , so apparently one method of prophylaxis against tritium poisoning is diuretics and increase fluid intake, but I'm wondering if there are others. The Wikipedia article on Cesium 137 claims that exposure can be treated with Prussian Blue. This: https://www.dhss.delaware.gov/dph/files/strontiumfaq.pdf claims that there are no direct treatments for Strontium-90

Comment: So I am wondering whether there are any measures one can take (Besides donning protective equipment) before being exposed to Strontium-90 and Cesium-137, rather than after.